# How to create multiple connections in Qt SQLite?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have already created a db with the tables. Now, I want to create multiple connections for each thread.

Here is my idea. I will create the  `QMap<pid_t,QSqlDatabase> m_sql_db_list;`

When the db operations are done, I will get the `pid_t gettid(void);` If the pid is present in the `QMap`, I will use that `QSqlDatabase` for the db operations. In case, it is not there, I will create a separate connection and will store the `QSqlDatabase` in the `QMap` corresponding to the thread id. My question is how should I create the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You use QSqlDatabase::addDatabase with named connections (see the documentation [here](http://QSqlDatabase::addDatabase)).